# Is the join of two irreducible varieties is irreducible? (reference + real fied)

Tags: algebraic-geometry

The following definition and theorem are taken from J.M. Landsberg, Tensors: Geometry and Applications, Graduate Studies in Mathematics, v. 128  (p. 118)

Definition 5.1.1.1:
The $join$ of two varieties $X$, $Y$ is
$$
J(X,Y)=\overline{\bigcup\limits_{x\in X,\ y\in Y,\ x\ne y} \mathbb P^1_{xy}}.
$$
Theorem 5.1.1.4: 
Joins and secant varieties of irreducible varieties are irreducible.

For the proof the author refers to p.144 of
Joe Harris, Algebraic Geometry: A First Course.
But this book contains the proof only for secant varieties.

I have not found any other books or papers where the statement

`` Join of two irreducible varieties is  irreducible''

is formulated explicitly. And I have not found the proof.

Question 1: Where I can find the proof for joins of intersecting varieties?

Question 2: Does the statement hold over $\mathbb R$? I will appreciate any references here.

Comment: What is $\mathbf P^1_{xy}$?

Comment: 1. I think the point in citing Harris' book is that you can adapt the proof since $\sigma(X) = J(X,X)$.

2. I don't have a copy of the book in front of me, though I am fairly certain he works over the complex numbers, but I don't know if this particular statement holds over $\mathbb{R}$. I would guess not.

Comment: @Bruno That notation means a copy of $\mathbb{P}^1$ going through the points $x$ and $y$.

Comment: $\mathbb P^1_{xy}$ denote the line containing $x$ and $y$

Answer (score 3):

I am going to prove that the join of two irreducible varieties is irreducible, but first, I am going to give a definition of join that is more easy to drive.

Let $X,Y\subseteq\mathbb{P}^{n}$ be two irreducible varieties. Let us consider
$$
S^{0}_{X,Y}:=\{(x,y,z)\in X\times Y\times \mathbb{P}^{N}:x\neq y, z\in\langle x,y\rangle\},
$$
and
$$
S_{X,Y}:=\overline{S^{0}_{X,Y}}\subseteq X\times Y\times\mathbb{P}^{N}
$$
(where the line means Zariski closure). Let us consider the projections
$$
\pi_{1}:S_{X,Y}\rightarrow X\times Y,
$$
$$
\pi_{2}:S_{X,Y}\rightarrow \mathbb{P}^{N}.
$$
We define the join of $X,Y$ to be 
$$
S(X,Y):=\pi_{2}(S_{X,Y}).
$$
The fibers of $\pi_{1}|_{S^{0}_{X,Y}}$ are isomorphic to lines, so they are irreducible of the same dimension. In consequence, $S^{0}_{X,Y}$ is irreducible. Accordingly, its Zariski closure $S_{X,Y}$ is irreducible, and the image of $S_{X,Y}$ under a morphism is irreducible too. In particular, $S(X,Y)=\pi_{2}(S_{X,Y})$ is irreducible, as we wanted to prove.

Answer (score 0):

Lemma. Let $X$ be an irreducible variety inside a grassmanian, $X\subset G(k,\mathbb{P}^n)$. Then the union of k-planes in $\mathbb{P}^n$ is irreducible.

proof. Consider the incidence correspondence $\{(p,V), p\in V\}\subset\mathbb{P}^n\times X$. It is easy now to see that the union of k-planes in $X$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{P}^n$. \qed

As a corollary, the Join is irreducible. The image of $X\times Y ---> Gr(1,n)$ is irreducible. Hence, the union of lines joining $X$ and $Y$ is also irreducibe.

Comment: I suppose you mean the union of the $k$-planes corresponding to the points of $X$ ? If so, please modify your answer.