# Intersection of projective varieties

Tags: algebraic-geometry, products, projective-varieties

Is there any way to study varieties of the form below

$$
X=V\left(\{ f_i,g_j|i\in I,j \in J \right\}) \subset \mathbb{P}^{m+n+1},
$$

where
$$
f_i \in k\left[ x_0, \cdots , x_m  \right],\ g_j\in k\left[ y_0, \cdots , y_n  \right].
$$

I want to know the relationship between  $ X$ and $X_1= V\left(\{ f_i|i\in I \}\right) \subset  \mathbb{P}^{m}$  , $X_2=V\left(\{ g_j|j\in J \}\right) \subset  \mathbb{P}^{n}$  .

For example, if $X_1$ and $X_2$ are irreducible, then so is $X$ or not.(eg. $V\left( x_0x_3-x_1x_2,x_4x_7-x_5x_6 \right)$ corresponds to $\mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^1$ )

Another example I care about is, if we know the Hilbert polynomials of $X_1$ and $X_2$, can we get the Hilbert polynomial of $X$？

I know similar question is "product" in case of affine, but I'm confused about projective case.

I'm guessing it might be a relationship I haven't learned yet, but I haven't looked it up.I'm sorry if this question seems stupid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given two non-intersecting projective varieties $X,Y\subset \mathbb{P}^d$, their join  (or more accurately, its set of closed points) is the union of all lines meeting both $X$ and $Y$. Once you have chosen the coordinates the way you did, with $\mathbb{P}^{n+m-1}$ having the coordinates $(x_0:\ldots:x_n:y_0:\ldots:y_m),$ you can check that what you describe is exactly the join of two subvarieties $X_1, X_2$, with $X_1$ embedded into $\mathbb{P}^n\subset\mathbb{P}^{n+m-1}$ cut out by $y_i=0$ and $X_2$ embedded into $\mathbb{P}^m\subset\mathbb{P}^{n+m-1}$ cut out by $x_j=0$.

The join of two irreducible varieties is irreducible. This is pretty evident from the geometric picture of lines joining two irreducible varieties, and the formal argument is [in an answer to 'Is the join of two irreducible varieties is irreducible?'](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1672996/422221).

The graded ring of the join is the tensor product of the graded rings of $X_1,X_2$ and the [Hilbert series of the join is just the product of Hilbert series of the two varieties](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4198666/422221). But from a glance, I don't think there is a simple description of the Hilbert polynomial of the join in terms of Hilbert polynomials of $X_1,X_2$.